# Access graph get series on 2 database fields

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

I have a technical issue with access graphs: I have a table in Access database with 4 fields: xValue, yValue, round, partOfRound

What I want: there are always 2 rounds, each round has 2 parts. I need to get a series per round per part (so from round 1 part 1, round 1 part 2, round 2 part 1, round 2 part 2) with all xValues and yValues in a chart.

But then I have an other problem:The xValue isn't a good number to show, this is needing to be this number divided by a number from an other table (see this as number in table3) where the row of table 3 equels the identifier with the identifier I use for my chart. (IDtable2=IDtable3)

The final result will be 4 lines with the data in my graph, so 4 series.

But when I use the wizard for making graphs, I can only set 1 field to the series value, so it will see a round as just 1 series instead of 2.

How do I solve this problem?

Kind regards
Kristof

Answer (score 0):

What type of graph - just a column?

Concatenate the round and partOfRound fields.

Try changing the graph RowSource to:

`TRANSFORM Sum(Table2.yValue) AS SumOfyValue SELECT Table2.xValue FROM Table2 GROUP BY Table2.xValue PIVOT [round] & "_" & [partOfRound];`

Possible SQL to include table join to calculate the division:

`TRANSFORM Sum(Table2.yValue) AS SumOfyValue
SELECT Round([xValue]/[Factor],0) AS x
FROM Table3 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table3.PK_Table3 = Table2.FK_Table3
GROUP BY Round([xValue]/[Factor],0)
PIVOT [round] & "_" & [partOfRound];`

For both queries, I had to open the graph editor (double click the graph) and from the menu click on "By Column" button to get the x values on the x axis.

I do hope round is not an actual name as it is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: It is about a line graph, but I will try your solution, I think it can work :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I have still one question: I need to divide the xValue with a value from an other table to show a value  where I can do something with. Is this possible?

Comment: Certainly. Modify your question with more info or start a new question.

Comment: What is the relationship of the tables? Is table3 a lookup table? It has PK that is saved as FK into table2? Could show actual table and field names.

Comment: Start a SELECT query that joins the tables. Pull fields into design grid, construct field with the division calc, switch to CROSSTAB, set the parameters. Can do this in the graph RowSource property.

Comment: I don't think I really understand your explanation of a possible solution, nor can I give you the actual table names and field names because of my contract with the company.
What I can say is that table2 is a linked table from an other database then table3, so there is no refference set in access. But there is a value that will always be unique, the ID wich is the same as the ID used for my form.

Comment: Then make up names as I suppose you did in your first paragraph. Didn't really answer my question about which is PK and which is FK. If these ID fields are both autonumber type, how can they have a relationship? Click the ellipsis in graph RowSource property to open query builder. See edited answer using my fabricated names.

Comment: They aren't an autonumber, it are ID's of products. Off course, I need info about the same product from both tables. You can see it as identic product names in both tables.

I will try to do something with your edited version, it gives me a couple off ideas :)